freeCodeCamp: Responsive Web Design - Survey Form Certification
I am trying to learn to code as a hobby, to preface all this. HTML and CSS seemed like a fun place to start, because building websites seemed intriguing to me.
I am going through the survey form certification of the responsive web design curriculum, and I cannot get the checkboxes to align to the left side of the form like I want. specifically, I want each checkbox to have its own line, aligned to the left side of the form, not listing one directly after another as it is currently formatted. I have searched online for remedies, and have tried many. However, I am not well-versed in this area, so any help would be appreciated. I will list my code below.


h1,p {
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(51, 0, 0);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

form {
  background-color: rgb(32,0,0);
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

input  {
  background-color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
}
  
.input-checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.625rem;
  min-height: 1 rem;
  min-width: 1 rem;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  height: 2em;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  background-color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
  border-color: white;
  min-width: 300px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Survey Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
<h1 id="title">freeCodeCamp Survey Form
</h1>
  <p id="description">Please answer below to help us improve our platform.</p>
  <hr>
  <body>
    <form id="survey-form">
      <label for="name">First and Last Name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your Name" required></input>
      <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email" required></input>
      <label for="age">Age (optional)</label>
        <input id id="number" type="number" min="13" max="120" name="age" placeholder="##"></input>
      <label for="referrer">How did you hear about us?</label>
        <select id="referrer" name="referrer">
          <option value="">(select one)</option>
          <option value="1">Youtube</option>
          <option value="2">TikTok</option>
          <option value="3">Online Forum</option>
          <option value="4">Other</option>
        </select>
      <legend>Select Your Gender:</legend>
        <label for="gender">
          <input id="Male" type="radio" name="gender" class="input-checkbox" checked></input>Male</label>
        <label for="gender">
          <input id="Female" type="radio" name="gender" class="input-checkbox"></input>Female</label>
        <label for="gender">
          <input id="Other" type="radio" name="gender" class="input-checkbox" ></input>Prefer not to disclose</label>
      <legend>What Core Curriculum have you explored on our platform, so far?</legend>
        <label for="projects">
          <input id="web-dev" type="checkbox" name="projects" value="web-dev" class="input-checkbox">Responsive Web Design</input>
          <input id="javascript" type="checkbox" name="projects" value="javascript" class="input-checkbox">Javascript Algorithms and Data Structures</label></input>
          <input id="front-end" type="checkbox" name="projects" value="front-end" class="input-checkbox">Front End Development</input>
          <input id="data-vis" type="checkbox" name="projects" value="data-vis" class="input-checkbox">Data Visualization</input>
          <input id="rel-data" type="checkbox" name="projects" value="rel-data" class="input-checkbox">Relational Databases</input>
          <input id="back-dev" type="checkbox" name="projects" value="back-dev" class="input-checkbox">Back End Development</input>
          <input id="q-a" type="checkbox" name="projects" value="q-a" class="input-checkbox">Quality Assurance</input>
          <input id="python" type="checkbox" name="projects" value="python" class="input-checkbox">Scientific Computing with Python</input>
          <input id="data-an" type="checkbox" name="projects" value="data-an" class="input-checkbox">Data Analysis with Python</input>
          <input id="info-sec" type="checkbox" name="projects" value="info-sec" class="input-checkbox">Information Security</input>
          <input id="machine-learning" type="checkbox" name="projects" value="machine-learning" class="input-checkbox">Machine Learning with Python</input>
          <input id="algebra" type="checkbox" name="projects" value="algebra" class="input-checkbox">College Algebra with Python</input>
        </label>
      <legend>Provide a Bio:</legend>
        <textarea id="bio" rows="3" cols="40" placeholder="I enjoy coding on the weekends..."></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

```



I have tried many different CSS formats to remedy this, but haven't found a solution yet. I took an overseas vacation between the last time I worked on this so I'm a bit fuzzy on all the avenues I took to try and solve this problem.

It can be helpful to first put your code through a validator, for example https://validator.w3.org/nu/ You have for example spurious input closures.

Your markup is completely invalid. <input> is a so-called replaced element and has no closing tag. Also, a label is only allowed to contain 1 input element. Actually, it is not a suitable case to be used for a label. It should be a sub-headline or <legend> within a <fieldset>.  the description that you put "inside" the inputs is the label. I would start with fixing your invalid markup and check it with a Markup Validator. Your incorrect markup causes a lot of unpredictable layout issues as the browser tries to fix your mistakes.

PS: While you use legend you missed that a legend is only valid as a direct child element of a fieldset and only one legend is allowed in each fieldset. Also, no tags are allowed between head and body.
